# Python itertools chain: possible to fill the shorter iterable with None

Tags: python, python-itertools, chain

When using the `itertools.chain` method to flatten a list like:

```
list(itertools.chain(*zip(itr1,itr2)))
```

Is it possible to fill the shorter iterable with None like in `itertools.imap` for example? So I won't end up with:

```
In [1]: a = [1]
In [2]: b=[]

In [3]: list(itertools.chain(*zip(a,b))) 
Out[3]: []
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you're pairing items, but there aren't matching pairs, then is a fillvalue actually okay? Given your example do you want `[1, None]` or would you prefer `[1]` ?

Comment: It is ok, but won't go into detail here. Let's just say the algorithm I need this data structure for isn't mother's prettiest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest), pass the default value to the `fillvalue` parameter.

Demo:

```
In [1]: from itertools import chain, izip_longest

In [2]: a = [1]

In [3]: b = []

In [5]: list(chain(*izip_longest(a, b, fillvalue='foo')))
Out[5]: [1, 'foo']
```

Default value of `fillvalue` is `None`.